# Make Angular client login to Spring backend with JWT

Tags: spring, angular, jwt

I added JWT to my Spring backend following this guide: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/

When I send a PUT request using a software like Postman everything works fine, but as soon as I'm trying to login with my Angular client the data in the `HttpServletRequest` is empty.

I check the data in the `attemptAuthentication` method of the `JWTLoginFilter` in the following way:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    String reqBody = req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

    // this appears to be empty on angular client calls
    System.out.println(reqBody);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true)
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
    AccountCredentials creds = objectMapper.readValue(reqBody, AccountCredentials.class);

    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                creds.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList()));
}
```

I'm sending the request out of the client like this:

```
const user = {
  username: "asdf",
  password: "asdf"
};

// imported from '@angular/http'
const headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
const body = JSON.stringify(user);
return this.http
  .put("http://localhost:8080/api/login", body, {headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json().data as User)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

My suggestion would be that I'm sending the request body in a wrong way, but I can't see, what I'm doing wrong.

I tried:

- sending the body as a regular JS object
- sending it wrapped in another object
- sending it as a JSON string as shown in the example
- using POST instead of PUT (although it works with PUT in Postman)
- changing the Content-Type Header to other values

None of this made any data appear in the backend.

If you need more information about anything, please ask me.

Comment: Are you using `spring-security-oauth2` dependency?

Comment: @PraveenM No, I'm using `spring-boot-starter-security@1.5.8.RELEASE` and `jjwt@0.7.0`.

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

I needed to allow CORS also on my `HttpSecurity` object as following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
      .and()
      .so()
      .on();
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure, why the requests I sent with Postman could get received without CORS enabled in my `HttpSecurity`, but nevertheless it's working now.

I hope I can help others with this in future.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the reason, Spring OAuth 2 normally expect a `POST` request with URL encoded username and password. So try something like this.

```
return this.http.post(Url, "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password)
```

I'm not 100% sure if this the case as mine was a `Spring-MVC`, but I expect it to be very similar.

Comment: This should not only be a Spring thing but a regular one. So Angular's http module should already take care about this. At least the post and put calls in the tutorial on the angular homepage passes the body data as JS objects

Comment: That depends on what's your Spring OAuth config. When you use Postman, do you send the Username and Password in the POST body or URL encoded?

Comment: I send it as a raw JSON string in the body.

Comment: I found the solution and added an answer. In case you're interested in it.